# Swipe-To-Delete triggers the insert row on my table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app, the user is presented with a table of data. When they click "edit", an edit row appears at the top with a green plus-sign - they can use this to add another item to the list.

This works fine when the user just taps the edit button, but if the users uses swipe-to-delete, the edit row appears (without the green plus) and everything goes weird (delete button appearing on the wrong row, etc).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Sorry just to dump a load of code but I've gone round in so many circles that I've lost all perspective!

```
#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"
#import "Checklist.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController (private)
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)addingView; 
@end


@implementation ChecklistsViewController
@synthesize category, managedObjectContext, fetchedResultsController;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        editControlsDidShow = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [category release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;    
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];    
    if (tableView.editing) return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] +1; 
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableView.editing) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Checklist";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        }
        if (indexPath.row != 0) {
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        } 
    }
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            // error code
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }    
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

        [self addingView];
    }   
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = indexPath.row;    
    if (self.editing && row == 0) {
        if (editControlsDidShow) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    editControlsDidShow = NO;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    NSArray *addRow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if (editing) {
        editControlsDidShow = YES;
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
    else {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // not done yet
}


#pragma mark - Data


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *aChecklist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [aChecklist.name description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [aChecklist.category.name description];
}


- (void) addingView// :(id)sender
{   
    //Create the root view controller for the navigation controller
    AddingViewController *viewController = [[AddingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddingViewController" bundle:nil];    
    viewController.delegate = self;
    viewController.title = @"Add Checklist";

    // Create the navigation controller and present it modally
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    viewController.textLabel.text = @"Enter new checklist name";

    [navigationController release];
    [viewController release];
}


#pragma mark - AddingViewDelegate


- (void)addingViewController:(AddingViewController *)addingViewController didAdd:(NSString *)itemAdded
{
    if (itemAdded != nil) {
        // Turn off editing mode.
        if (self.editing) [self.navigationController setEditing:NO animated:NO];        
        // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        Checklist *newChecklist = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [category addChecklistsObject:newChecklist];
        newChecklist.name = itemAdded;        

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            // error code
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }     
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Checklist" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // Set 4* the predicate so we only see checklists for this category.
    NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.name = %@", self.category.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];    
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];    
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];    
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
       // handle the error properly!
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
} 


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one thing that you probably want to change:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

I don't think you want the edit row to be editable. Here's code to fix that:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.row != 0);
}
```

You might want an if else to make it more readable, but if you're lazy this will suffice.

Also could you point out where you add the green plus-sign? I'll update my answer when you do.

**EDIT:** The problem is that when you use swipe-to-delete only the row you swipe enters edit mode. The edit row doesn't enter edit mode and therefore the green plus-sign isn't shown. If the delete button is appearing on the wrong row, I would assume that the problem is that when the table view enters edit mode the edit row is added, which updates the indexPaths of all consecutive rows.

As of right now I cannot provide any code for how to solve the problem, but I can provide you with an idea. You shouldn't add the edit row when the user uses swipe-to-delete. If you can identify when swipe-to-delete is used and not add the edit row based on that your problem should be solved. I've never had a similar problem, so I've never had to do this. Thus I can't provide the details on how to do this.

If you need more/better advise or help with the implementation, let me know.

Comment: Look at the return type of `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`. It's a `BOOL`. Returning the row index is nonsensical. ;p

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan `indexPath.row` is an integer and if that integer is 0 the return value is false, else it's true. It beats writing the if else statement without auto completion on stackoverflow. In real life you want to avoid confusing your co-workers.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan I edited the answer so that it's less confusing.

Comment: @Erik B I know what a `BOOL` is. I'm saying that as it *was* written (you fixed it) it could be mistaken for a bug--and it is, since if the index > `127`, it could truncate to `0`!

Comment: @Erik Unfortunately this change makes it worse - now it doesn't work when the edit button is pressed either! The insert row does not indent with the other rows, and the green plus is not visible. The green plus is created in tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath (when editing, it adds a row at the top which is UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert). Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @Ric Levy: Perhaps you should tell @Erik B, then, as it's his answer?

Comment: @Jonathan oops, sorry! I've fixed the name.

Comment: @Ric Levy I'm glad I helped track down the problem. I understand now why it isn't working. I will update the answer to explain why it doesn't work and hopefully I will find a solution for you as well. I'm kinda busy right now, but hopefully you won't have to wait for too long.

Comment: @Erik - I've tried implementing your suggestion as best I can (being a beginner) and it's better but I've got stuck again. Now everything works except deleting when in Edit mode after pressing the Edit button. I'd really appreciate any further advice you could give me! To avoid confusion, I've started a new question [which is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410464/uitable-view-in-edit-mode-pressing-delete-makes-my-app-crash). Thanks!

Comment: @Ric Levy - I suppose you should accept this answer then. Also I've taken a look at your new question and I think I might have a solution for you. I'll share it with you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and I just fixed it with this trick:

You can check *how* editing mode was set to YES in this vein:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    editingFromSwipe = YES;
    [super tableView:tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    editingFromSwipe = NO;
}
```

And I guess that you already know how you proceed from this point, you create an if-function inserting the add-row-row only when editingFromSwipe is zero.

I think that we all agree that Apple is not very cooperative here. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact answer I'm looking for. And OMG, one more level of if statements in my UITableView code.