# UITableView In Edit Mode - Pressing Delete Makes My App Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

My UITableView has an Edit button which adds an "insert row" (with a green plus). If I try to delete a row while in Edit mode, my app crashes with "NSRangeException". Deleting a row while NOT in edit mode (using swipe-to-delete) is fine.

I know this is to do with how many rows the table view thinks it has - getting an insert row and swipe-to-delete both to work in the same table is a nightmare (for a beginner like me) because both swiping and pressing the edit button put the table in "edit mode", but the edit button adds a row, whereas swiping doesn't.

I've been trying to use a couple of Ivars to overcome this, but clearly I've gone wrong somewhere. Can someone more experienced tell me where I'm going wrong? (I'm sure I'm going about this in far too complicated a way!).

EDIT - as requested by Chiefly Izzy, I've put my whole unedited .m file here.

```
//
//  ChecklistsViewController.m
//  Check Box
//
//  Created by Ric on 18/03/2011.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"
#import "Checklist.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController (private)
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)addingView;
@end


@implementation ChecklistsViewController

@synthesize category, managedObjectContext, fetchedResultsController;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        editingFromSwipe = NO;
        tableIsEditing = NO;
        NSLog(@"tableIsEditing = NO (init) \n");
        NSLog(@"Not Editing From Swipe (init) \n");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [category release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    editingFromSwipe = NO;
    tableIsEditing = NO;
    NSLog(@"tableIsEditing = NO (viewDidLoad) \n");
    NSLog(@"Not Editing From Swipe (viewDidLoad) \n");

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;    
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection HAS BEEN CALLED");
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    int rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    if (self.editing) {
        if (!editingFromSwipe && tableIsEditing) {
            NSLog(@"Returning extra row - editing not from swipe \n");
            return rows +1;
        }
        NSLog(@"Returning normal rows - editing from swipe \n");
        return rows;
    }
    NSLog(@"Returning normal rows - not editing - and setting tableIsEditing back to NO \n"); 
    tableIsEditing = NO;
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    NSLog(@"Should go into if statement here! \n");

    if (tableView.editing) { //
        if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (!editingFromSwipe)) {
            NSLog(@"Configuring Add Button Cell while editing \n");
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Checklist";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Configuring other cells while editing \n");
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Configuring Cell Normally While Not Editing \n");
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }


    return cell;
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
/*
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // return (indexPath.row != 0);
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];        
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }    
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        [self addingView];

    }   
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = indexPath.row;

    if (self.editing && row == 0) {
        if (!editingFromSwipe && tableIsEditing) {
            NSLog(@"Not from swipe so making first row style insert button \n");
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }
        else if (editingFromSwipe) { 
            NSLog(@"Is from swipe so making first row delete rather than insert \n");
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"Not editing or not first row so making cell style normal \n");
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    editingFromSwipe = YES;
    // NSLog(@"Editing From Swipe (just swiped) \n");
    [super tableView:tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    editingFromSwipe = NO;
    // NSLog(@"Not Editing From Swipe (just unswiped) \n");
}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    NSArray *addRow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (!editingFromSwipe) {
        if (editing) {
            NSLog(@"Editing called while swipe off, so adding insert row \n");
            tableIsEditing = YES;
            NSLog(@"tableIsEditing = YES (setEditing:Animated:)");
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
        else {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        } 
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
         <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];
         */
    }
}


#pragma mark - Data


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *aChecklist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = aChecklist.name; // description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aChecklist.category.name; // description];
}


- (void) addingView// :(id)sender
{
    // Turn off edit mode if it is on.
    //if (self.editing) {
    //    [self.navigationController setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    //}

    //Create the root view controller for the navigation controller
    AddingViewController *viewController = [[AddingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddingViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.delegate = self;
    viewController.title = @"Add Checklist";

    // Create the navigation controller and present it modally
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    viewController.textLabel.text = @"Enter new checklist name";

    [navigationController release];
    [viewController release];
}


#pragma mark - AddingViewDelegate


- (void)addingViewController:(AddingViewController *)addingViewController didAdd:(NSString *)itemAdded
{
    if (itemAdded != nil) {

        // Turn off editing mode.
        if (self.editing) [self.navigationController setEditing:NO animated:NO];

        // Add the category name to our model and table view.

        // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        Checklist *newChecklist = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [category addChecklistsObject:newChecklist];

        newChecklist.name = itemAdded;        
        // [newChecklist setDateStamp:[NSDate date]];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }


    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Checklist" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // Set 4* the predicate so we only see checklists for this category.
    NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.name = %@", self.category.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];    
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];    
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];    
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".    

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
       // handle the error properly!
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
} 


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 */




@end
```

---

---

EDIT: Here is the new code in my 'tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath' method, based on Erik B's advice:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

        int numberOfRows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
        int rowBeingDeleted = indexPath.row +1;

        if (tableIsEditing && !editingFromSwipe && numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted) {
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]]];
        }
        else {
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        }

        // context saving code    
    }      
}
```

The app no longer crashes, and swipe-to-delete is still fine, but if try to delete the last row while in Edit mode, it deletes the second-last row instead. All the other rows are fine. (My insert row is at the top, incidentally).

Comment: Ric, can you post the whole .m file? Your tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: looks ok. P.S. Do not use abort() in your code.

Comment: @Chiefly Izzy - I've replaced the first code segment above with my whole .m file. Any help would be gratefully appreciated! The abort() is just part of Apple's boilerplate on new CoreData files - I haven't had a chance to replace (ahem, learn about) the error codes yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what we know: You get `NSRangeException` on this line:

```
[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

`deleteObject:` doesn't throw `NSRangeException`, so we know that

```
[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

is causing the crash. The most probable cause for this is that you don't take into account that the table view's index path isn't the same as the `fetchedResultsController`'s index path when you have added the "insert row".

If I'm right it should only crash when you delete the last row.

This is how you fix it:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]]
```

Keep in mind that you should only change the index path if the "insert row" is visible.

**EDIT:**

> Deleting the row just below the insert row works fine. I can delete any row with swipe-to-delete, and using the edit button I can delete any row except the last row (which deletes the row above it instead).

```
if (tableIsEditing && !editingFromSwipe && numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted) {
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]]];
} else {
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

So this is what's causing that bug:

```
numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted
```

You only change the index path if it's the last row. This is confusing, but maybe you shouldn't change the index path then? Try replacing `numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted` with `NO` and see what happens.

**EDIT 2:** What happens if you do this instead?

```
if (tableIsEditing && !editingFromSwipe) {
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]]];
} else {
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Erik - I am learning a lot! :-) I am away from the computer now but I will try this tomorrow. While I'm here, I hope you don't mind if I impose on you once more for some advice. I've used those two ivars ('editingFromSwipe' and 'tableIsEditing') to keep track of how many rows there are in my table, and it seems to work, but I feel like I've overcomplicated it (with 2 ivars whose bool values are being reset all over the place).  Is there a more elegant way that I could have got my insert row and swipe-to-delete to play nice? I'm sure it must be possible with just one ivar.

Comment: @Erik B, I've tried to incorporate that code (invoking it whenever both the edit button has been pressed and the user tries to delete the last row) and it has fixed the crash, but now the second-last row gets deleted instead! I've edited my question and added the new code.

Comment: @Ric Levy, What happens if you delete the row just below the insert row?

Comment: @Erik B, Deleting the row just below the insert row works fine. I can delete any row with swipe-to-delete, and using the edit button I can delete any row except the last row (which deletes the row above it instead).

Comment: @Ric Levy, That sounds weird, but if it works the way you describe it there is an easy way to fix it. I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: @Erik B - "Try replacing numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted with NO and see what happens." Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the sentence! Do you mean "number of Rows !rowBeingDeleted"?

Comment: @Ric Levy, I meant literally. The effect would be that you never change the index path. That's why it's confusing. To clarify: `if (tableIsEditing && !editingFromSwipe && NO)`. It looks stupid, because it will always be false, but that's the point. I was in a hurry when I wrote this, otherwise I would probably express myself differently.

Comment: @Erik B, ah I see. If I replace it with NO, then deleting the last row actually causes my insert row to disappear instead. Deleting any other row still seems to be fine.

Comment: @Ric Levy, You know that is really confusing. My edit already contradicts my original answer and now this?!? How is this even possible? The change you just made basically undoes the fix for the crash. It sounds like you've changed something else too. I'm starting to feel like we've fixed the crash, which was your original question, so maybe it's time to start a new question for this new problem, just like you did with your last question?

Comment: @Erik, I don't think I've changed other stuff, but this has been taxing my brain so much that it's quite possible I've lost track of what I've been doing! I'm starting to think I should just find a solution to my app that doesn't require adding an insert row, but I also think that solving this is a really important learning experience! I've taken your suggestion and put this up as a new question. Thanks again for all your help, and if you're still up for the challenge, the new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434383/why-cant-i-delete-the-bottom-row-of-my-uitableview).

Comment: @Ric Levy, It doesn't make sense that the insert row would disappear. You're deleting from `fetchedResultsController` and the insert row doesn't even exist in `fetchedResultsController`. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @Erik, Aha! I have a clue! When I try to delete the bottom row, it appears to delete the row above. But if I quit and reload the app, it turns out the bottom row has gone after all. It's similar but slightly different when I put the "NO" in - it appears to delete the insert row, but actually it has deleted the top data row. So I think this is something to do with the UITableView getting out of sync with the NSFetchedResultsController. Does this help? (I'm going to add this to my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434383/why-cant-i-delete-the-bottom-row-of-my-uitableview)).

Comment: @Ric Levy, "It appears to delete the row above, but if I immediately quit and reload the app, it turns out the bottom row has gone after all." Does this mean that the ones you thought worked really doesn't?

Comment: @Ric Levy, I don't know what kind of project you're working on, but it seems like you're at liberty to share as much code as you feel like. You don't happen to have a github or bitbucket repository from which I can download your entire project? I think it would be easier to find the problem if I could run the app myself.

Comment: @Erik there's a promising answer on my other question suggesting that, basically, an NSFetchedResultsController is not designed with additional rows in mind.  They suggest putting a button in the table's header view instead. Do you agree?

Comment: @Ric Levy, Well, his solution will work, but it is a different design decision. I myself always use an add button in the nav bar, just like contacts is doing it. Anyway, I think I have an idea of how to make your original design work.