# Why Can't I delete the bottom row of my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When the user presses Edit, my UITableView adds an insert row at the top (with a green plus), and puts all the other rows into delete mode (red minus). Alternatively, the user can swipe-to-delete without pressing the edit button. I am using a couple of Ivars to keep track of whether the table is in edit mode from a swipe, or from pressing the edit button, and act accordingly (e.g. updating numberOfRowsInTableView: with the extra insert row when Edit has been pressed).

Everything works perfectly except on thing: when in Edit mode (i.e. the user has explicitly hit the edit button, and the insert row has appeared at the top), if the user tries to delete the bottom row, the next row up gets deleted instead. Deleting any other row is fine.

**EDIT** -- It *appears* to delete the row above, but if I immediately quit and reload the app, it turns out the bottom row has gone after all. So I'm guessing my UITableView is going out of sync with my NSFetchedResultsController somewhere.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"
#import "Checklist.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController (private)
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)addingView;
@end


@implementation ChecklistsViewController

@synthesize category, managedObjectContext, fetchedResultsController;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        editingFromSwipe = NO;
        tableIsEditing = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [category release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    editingFromSwipe = NO;
    tableIsEditing = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;    
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    int rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    if (self.editing) {
        if (!editingFromSwipe && tableIsEditing) {
            return rows +1;
        }
        return rows;
    }
    tableIsEditing = NO;
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    NSLog(@"Should go into if statement here! \n");

    if (tableView.editing) { //
        if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (!editingFromSwipe)) {
            NSLog(@"Configuring Add Button Cell while editing \n");
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Checklist";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Configuring other cells while editing \n");
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Configuring Cell Normally While Not Editing \n");
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

        int numberOfRows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
        int rowBeingDeleted = indexPath.row +1;

        if (tableIsEditing && !editingFromSwipe && numberOfRows == rowBeingDeleted) {
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]]];
        }
        else {
            [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        }

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            // TO DO: Fix error code.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }    
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        [self addingView];        
    }   
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = indexPath.row;

    if (self.editing && row == 0) {
        if (!editingFromSwipe && tableIsEditing) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }
        else if (editingFromSwipe) { 
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }

    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    editingFromSwipe = YES;
    [super tableView:tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    editingFromSwipe = NO;
}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    NSArray *addRow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (!editingFromSwipe) {
        if (editing) {
            tableIsEditing = YES;
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
        else {
           [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        } 
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
        TO DO: Code for when row is selected
    }
}


#pragma mark - Data


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *aChecklist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = aChecklist.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aChecklist.category.name;
}


- (void) addingView// :(id)sender
{
    AddingViewController *viewController = [[AddingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddingViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.delegate = self;
    viewController.title = @"Add Checklist";

    // Create the navigation controller and present it modally
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    viewController.textLabel.text = @"Enter new checklist name";

    [navigationController release];
    [viewController release];
}


#pragma mark - AddingViewDelegate


- (void)addingViewController:(AddingViewController *)addingViewController didAdd:(NSString *)itemAdded
{
    if (itemAdded != nil) {

        // Turn off editing mode.
        if (self.editing) [self.navigationController setEditing:NO animated:NO];

        // Add the category name to our model and table view.

        // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        Checklist *newChecklist = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [category addChecklistsObject:newChecklist];

        newChecklist.name = itemAdded;        
        // [newChecklist setDateStamp:[NSDate date]];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            TO DO: fix error code.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }


    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Checklist" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // Set 4* the predicate so we only see checklists for this category.
    NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.name = %@", self.category.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];    
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];    
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];    
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".    

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
       // TO DO: error stuff
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
} 


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {       
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

Comment: The next time you want to post 378 lines of code, just provide a link to a file.

Comment: I would caution you not to make your tableviews to complex. I think trying to edit data within a tableview cell is almost always a mistake. There is just to much going on in a tableview to throw in editing as well. To create a new row, use a detail view. That is what the interface grammar has taught users to expect.

Comment: @TechZen excuse my unfamiliarity with the terminology, but what do you mean by use a detail view? I associate 'detail view' with loading a whole new view (such as loading a table of child entities when the user selects a parent item). How can I add a row to a table with a detail view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design it at fault. You shouldn't be adding rows anywhere but where they logically go in  the table.

The entire point of a fetched results controller (FRC) is to synchronize the tableview with the data. The order of the rows in the table should reflect the order of managed objects in the fetchedObjects array. By inserting a row at the bottom or top and while adding an object that does not necessarily logically belong at the top or bottom of the table, are breaking that synchronization.

When you add a new managed object in `addingViewController:didAdd:` the FRC alerts it delegate which tries to redraw the table. You've tried to compensate for this but you really can't. All you indexes are coming off.

Instead of using a row to input new rows. Use a tableview header or footer view. That way, you can freeze the tableview, create the new object, then update the table and the new object will show up where it logical belongs in the table.

Comment: Thanks. Being a newbie, I had no idea that it was possible to do that with a table header, but a bit of googling seems to confirm that I should be able to stick a button up there and handle this in a more elegant way. I suspect the previous examples I've seen of using an insert row must not have been using an NSFetchedResultsController, and that is probably where I have got stuck. I'll give this a try when I'm back at my comouter then I'll come back here and let you know how I got on.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I found [this guide](http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/04/putting-button-in-table.html) on adding buttons to tables, and it took about 5 minutes to implement. I'll also be able to customise the button this way and it should 'scale' easily if I change my table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add static cells to UITableViews that get their data from a NSFetchedResultsController. But to do this you have to adjust almost all NSIndexPaths that are used within one of the `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` or `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.

I added some helper methods that translate the indexpath of the tableview to the indexpath of the fetched resultscontroller and the other way around. Something like this could be used if you want to add a row on top:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableIndexPathFromNSFRCIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip {
    if (editingMode && ip.section == 0) {
        NSIndexPath *newIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ip.row+1 inSection:ip.section];
        return newIP;
    }
    return ip;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)nsfrcIndexPathFromTableIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip {
    if (editingMode && ip.section == 0) {
        NSIndexPath *newIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ip.row-1 inSection:ip.section];
        return newIP;
    }
    return ip;
}
```

and then you have to change every method that passes an indexpath from the table to the fetchedresultscontroller or from the frc to the table. I show you two as an example.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    newIndexPath = [self tableIndexPathFromNSFRCIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    indexPath = [self tableIndexPathFromNSFRCIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.listTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.listTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.listTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.listTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.listTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (editingMode && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Add New entry...
    }
    else {
        indexPath = [self nsfrcIndexPathFromTableIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To not get the rows mixed up I would suggest putting the insert row in its own section. Since you're obviously just using one section you know that the section you send to FRC should always be 0. The code would be as simple as:

```
[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]]];
```

TechZen's solution will also work, so which solution you choose is entirely about what design you prefer. TechZen's solution doesn't interfere with having multiple sections, but this solution could be modified to support multiple sections as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help Erik. In the end, I've gone with TechZen's suggestion but I have learned an enormous amount from you over the last few days, and my general programming knowledge is all the better for it!